# Combine multiple lines with Regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this text:

> phoneNumber: "090-1234567"
> specialisms: ["Hotel", "House", "Space", "Room", "Street", "Office", "Car",…]
> 0: "Hotel"
> 1: "House"
> 2: "Space"
> 3: "Room"
> 4: "Street"
> 5: "Office"
> 6: "Car"
> 7: "Construction"
> 8: "Monument"
> 9: "Building"
> 10: "Rental"
> 11: "Stores"
> website:http://www.hophophop.xyz
> phoneNumber: "06-12121233"
> specialisms: ["Advice", "Business", "Sales", "Living", "Routing", "Offices",…]
> 0: "Advice"
> 1: "Business"
> 2: "Sales"
> 3: "Living"
> 4: "Routing"
> 5: "Offices"
> 6: "Spaces"
> website:https://Idonthaveone.com

I would like to get it like this:

> phoneNumber: "079-3428777"
> specialisms: Hotel, House, Space, Room, Street, Office, Car, Construction, Monument, Building, Rental, Stores
> website:http://www.hophophop.xyz
> phoneNumber: "06-12121233"
> specialisms: Advice, Business, Sales, Living, Routing, Offices, Spaces
> website:https://Idonthaveone.com

With this code, I can find alle text between "specialisms" and "website..."

```
(^spec.*?)(web.*?\r\n)
```

But then it stops for me. I know basic regex, but this one is just ehm..complicated.
Who can help me with this one?
Regards, Peter

Comment: are you using any programming language apart from regex ?

Comment: No, I am no programmer. I build websites, and I do some scraping. That's it.

Comment: This can get you started: https://regex101.com/r/Pdu9Ph/1  `\n\d|\[|\]|"` but you'll probably need to do a few regexes

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in three easy steps:

1. Replacing `(?<=specialisms: )\[.*]` with an empty string with get rid of the `[...]` content.
2. Replacing `\r\n\d+: "([^"]*)"` with `\1,`  will put all listed items on the same (previous) line
3. Replacing `, \r\n` with `\r\n` will get rid of the trailing commas/whitespaces introduced by the previous operation

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single step.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[.+?\]|\R\d+: "(.+?)"(\Rweb)?`
- Replace with: `(?1$1(?2$2:, ))`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[.+?\]         # everything that is present between "[" & "]"
  |               # OR
\R              # any kind of linebreak
\d+:            # 1 or more digits followed by a colon and a space
"(.+?)"         # capture value between double quotes
(\Rweb)?        # group 2, optional, linebreak and "web"
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists
    $1          # print it
    (?2         # if group 2 exists
        $2          # print it
    :           # else
        ,           # print a comma and a space
    )           # endif
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Nicely done with the conditionals ++